# Is there other ways to center text in button, xml for android>

Tags: android, xml

I have searched but and tried different things but i still can fully center my text on one of my applications i started

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add one"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/bSub"
          android:layout_width="250dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:text="Subtract one"
          android:textSize="20dp" />
```

the text is still a little too much to the right,

any one have an idea on how it can be shifted to the cneter

Comment: Why don't you use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and add `android:padding` to your `Button`?

Comment: just replace `android:layout_gravity="center"` with `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: You will also need to change the textSize to "sp" from "dp"

Answer (score 3):

Use 
    `android:gravity="center"`this will place the text in center.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/bSub"
      android:layout_width="250dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Subtract one"
      android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Replace android:layout_gravity="center" to android:gravity="center" It will center the text

Answer (score 0):

```
try this way
1 . when you set android:layout_gravity="center" properties to button it put button on center of parent rather put text on center.
2.  in your case you have to set text of button center to button so you have to set android:gravity="center" rather this one android:layout_gravity="center"
```